# Use Ctrl-X commands while in terminal in emacs?

Tags: emacs, terminal

When I'm running a terminal inside emacs (with `M-x term`) I can't seem to use commands that start with `C-X`, such as, say `C-x o` to switch panes or `C-x C-c` to exit. Instead it seems that the terminal itself is receiving these `C-x` signals. By contrast, `C-c` commands are received by emacs itself. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 5):

`term` has two different input submodes.  In the default (character) mode, `C-x` simply transmits a literal <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> to the terminal.  Many keybindings which are normally available in the `C-x` map are instead now in the `C-c` map, so you can switch to a different buffer in the other window with `C-c 4 b`.  Or you can switch to line mode with `C-c C-j` (and back to character mode with `C-c C-k`).

See also [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html#Term-Mode).

Comment: This was substantially copy/pasted from an earlier answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/a/27197264/874188 where however the main problem turned out to be that the OP was using `evil`.