# Gnome key binding in ssh

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, emacs

Here's my scenario:
I connect to my debian server from an Ubuntu terminal. I invoke emacs text editor to edit files on my server. Unfortunately it seems that the `Ctrl X`key is not recognized by emacs run in this manner. I tried all available terminals including lxterminal, qterminal, xfceterminal while running ssh. It happens in all of them. I even tried the virtual console. It happens there too. It does not happen when connected from Windows via putty.

On the client, I tried nano in terminal mode  and `emacs -nw`, and Ctrl-X does work there. So I assume it's an emacs problem tied to ssh from Ubuntu. How do I fix this?

The client is running Ubuntu 16.10 on gnome. The host is Debian 8 x64 server.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567522/use-ctrl-x-commands-while-in-terminal-in-emacs

Comment: No, @piyushjaiswal. That answer is not helpful.

Comment: You haven't confirmed whether Ctrl-X works outside of Emacs in the first scenario. (You mentioned testing in Nano, but only in the same situation in which it also worked in Emacs.)

Comment: @phils It was confined to emacs. Unfortunately it started working after a couple of updates and a reboot. So I'm left clueless as to what it was.